# Is there a typo in the solution or is it incorrect?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> 2. Show that $(1+i)^i=\exp(-\frac\pi4+2n\pi)\exp(i\frac{\log2}2),n=0,\pm1,\dots$
>
> *Solution.*
> $$(1+i)^i=\exp(i\log(1+i)),$$
> $$\log(1+i)=\log|1+i|+i\arg(1+i)=\log\sqrt{1^2+1^2}+i\arctan\frac11+i2\pi n$$
> $$=\frac12\log2+i\frac\pi4+i2\pi n,$$
> $$i\log(1+i)=-\frac\pi4+2n\pi+i\frac{\log2}2,$$
> $$(1+i)^i=\exp(i\log(1+i))=\exp\left(-\frac\pi4+2n\pi+i\frac{\log2}2\right)=\exp\left(-\frac\pi4+2n\pi\right)\exp\left(i\frac{\log2}2\right).$$

On the fourth line of the solution, shouldn't it be $-2n\pi$ instead of $+2n\pi$?
$$i\log(1+i)=-\frac\pi4-2n\pi+i\frac{\log2}2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent; since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you can take the negative of their $n$ and get your version (which is still in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: that follows from properties of the log: $\log (a^n) = n \log (a)$